# How can i fix thix batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation

Hello I have a problem with a script, I would like the following from this script. First of all I want to create a folder with the month specific to my computer and in that folder to events logs,but save only application event and system event without the security even if the script is run with admin rights nothing happens. Bellow is my script

```
@echo off
rem Script starts here
rem Timestamp Generator
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set "dt=%%a"
:: Format the WMIC command output in YY_MM_DD_hr_mn format
set "YY=%dt:~0,4%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "hr=%dt:~8,2%"
set "mn=%dt:~10,2%"
:: Format the MM (month-number) to display the month-name
if %MM%==01 set MM=Ianuarie
if %MM%==02 set MM=Februarie
if %MM%==03 set MM=Martie
if %MM%==04 set MM=Aprilie
if %MM%==05 set MM=Mai
if %MM%==06 set MM=Iunie
if %MM%==07 set MM=Iulie
if %MM%==08 set MM=August
if %MM%==09 set MM=Septembrie
if %MM%==10 set MM=Octombrie
if %MM%==11 set MM=Noiembrie
if %MM%==12 set MM=Decembrie
set "today_date_time=%MM%_%YY%"
echo %today_date_time%
mkdir .\%today_date_time%
rem Set the timestamp format
wevtutil epl System %MM%_%YY%\system.evtx
wevtutil epl Application %MM%_%YY%\application.evtx
wevtutil epl Security %MM%_%YY%\security.evtx
wmic nteventlog where filename='system' cleareventlog
wmic nteventlog where filename='application' cleareventlog
wmic nteventlog where filename='security' cleareventlog
rem End of Script
```

Comment: Your code works correctly for me. Try opening the command prompt and running the script from there instead of double-clicking it to see if you get an error message.

Comment: I'm not understanding why you're doing it like that, why not choose one or the other? For instance, using `WMIC.exe`, you can use `nteventlog` with the `BackUpEventLog` method, just like you are intending with the `ClearEventLog` method. Alternatively using `wevtutil.exe` you could just do it in one go, `%SystemRoot%\System32\wevtutil.exe cl Application /bu:"%today_date_time%\application.evtx"`, which will backup the events before clearing them. As for `Security`, are you sure you even have one? `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe nteventlog Get FileName` should show you those which exist.

Comment: I ran the program with administrator rights from cmd as you said but it didn't generate the event called Security for me. Forget a picture https://ibb.co/JH5rQYK , What I would like to ask you is how I could create a subfolder in the month folder and this newly generated folder should have the name of the computer.

Comment: Compo you can show me in the code please I do not understand what you mean I am new in batch script.

Comment: Of course @Hadad, give me a few minutes to type something up in the Answer area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a re-written example without all of the WMIC.exe stuff, as per your commented request:

```sh
@Rem Start of script.
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Rem End script if end user is not running with the required permissions.
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKU\S-1-5-19" 1>NUL 2>&1 || GoTo :EOF
Rem Add the current directory to the stack and make this scripts location the current directory.
PushD "%~dp0."
Rem Generate a datestamp variable with a string formatted as yy_MMMM.
Set "DateStamp="
For /F %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile "Get-Date -F 'yy_MMMM'" 2^>NUL') Do Set "DateStamp=%%G"
Rem End script if datestamp variable was not defined.
If Not Defined DateStamp GoTo :EOF
Rem Backup and clear event logs.
If Not Exist "%DateStamp%\" MD "%DateStamp%"
For %%G In (Application Security System) Do %SystemRoot%\System32\wevtutil.exe cl %%G /bu:"%DateStamp%\%%G.evtx"
Rem Make the previous directory in the stack the current directory.
PopD
Rem End of Script.
```

*The script was designed to just close, if the end user did not Run as administrator. Also the backup files will be saved to the same location as the running batch file.*

Comment: It doesn't work for me https://ibb.co/hKyVH1z here have a photo with cmd

Comment: I have fixed my typo in the above code @Hadad. Please also try running the batch file from somewhere else, instead of from a network location, `\\VBOXSVR\share-folder`. I would assume that it is not able to write to that location as is. If that works, I'll consider revising the above.

Comment: It still doesn't work, I also ran the code on my pc and it doesn't work

Comment: Please try the revised version above, from your original location if needed. And if it does not do what is intended, instead of just putting "it doesn't work", try providing sufficient information for other readers, or myself to identify possible reasons. We expect all messages, debugging information, whether any of the files were created etc.

Comment: I'm sorry for the expression, it doesn't generate any of the 3 logs for me, I ran the script with administrator rights, here is a picture https://ibb.co/tmFDn1h

Comment: @Hadad, please verify, that you are using the latest edited version of the above code. An edit was made to create the destination directory, if it did not already exist. _(I had assumed, possibly incorrectly, that you must have already had a directory named `21_Decembrie` for your destination files)_.

Comment: It works, thank you very much, what else would I like to ask you how I could create a subfolder with the name of the computer in which to find the logs?

Comment: and how could I reward you?

Comment: Once again, thank you very much for your time if you could tell me where I could learn all these sincere things, I really didn't know about these commands. Another question I would have is how can all these folders be saved in a predefined way?

Comment: @Hadad you can learn a lot just by visiting the StackOverFlow every day and reading the questions and answers.